# One word, preferably an adverb, for "in one sitting"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am a little tight on paper space and I need to write >in one sitting<, or something of the sort, down but >in one sitting< will not fit onto the paper. So I need a single, concise word that has the same definition of in one sitting.
Here is a sentence to help. I want to do all of my homework [in one sitting].

Comment: "at once"?  It's a little shorter.

Comment: "At stretch"? Will it work?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would the opposite of this be smth like, at batches, one/little at a time?

Comment: "I want to do all of my homework now".  Maybe too simple, but it's short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one sitting is an idiom which means doing work for long time sitting without stopping now substitute word for the idiom in the sentence . I want to do all of my homework in one sitting could be I want to do all of my homework  **SEDENTARY** or you can use word **DESK-BOUND**.

Comment: you can also say i want to do my homework continually.  you can also us words like tirelessly ,,relentlessly etc

Comment: pardon my ignorance i am novice to stack community !

Answer (score 2):

Well if it's space and not word count:

> I want to do all of my homework **in one go**.

If you don't mind the added ambiguity (can be taken as "now"):

> I want to do all of my homework **at once**.

If it is the word count and you don't mind sounding like a vocabulary nerd:

> I want to do all of my homework **contiguously**